# Navigation in Vue.js

Tags: navigation, vuejs2, vue-router

I have below code in my HTML Code.

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/word/',name: 'word', params: { id: word._id }}"></router-link>
```

My route settings in `index.js` like below

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'mainbody',
            component: MainBody
        },
        {
            path: '/word/:id',
            name: 'word',
            component: Word
        }
    ]
});
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<router-link :to="'/word/' + word._id"></router-link>`